# Hadoop: Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop

I've some questions on mapreduce for HDFS.

Questions:

1. What is the default numbers of workers (map/reduce task) in each node of HDFS.
2. Which is better approach to access multiple blocks parallelly in a node and why.

   a. Creating multiple tasktrackers.
   b. Creating multiple workers (map/reduce task) per tasktracker.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

## 1)

By default:
The number of slots on a node is equal to the number of Cores (CPU Cores).
One task (either it is a Map task or a Reduce task) is executed on one slot.

## 2)

I think the second approach is better - having multiple tasks run on a task tracker.
Because, from performance point of view, what really matters is not the count of tasks but the distance between the Task Node (ie task tracker) and the Data Node. So, if all tasks are being run on the closest TaskTracker, then the performance will be better (not sure if hadoop can reuse the network connection. If yes, it will be an added advantage). In case, if multiple task trackers are created, some of them could be far away from the Data Node. So, the performance will obviously be low.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, Well correct me if I am wrong, If I have 3 blocks A,B,C and three slots 1,2,3 then I can say that slot 1,2,3 will perform simultaneous read on respective blocks A,B,C. In other words all blocks will be read parallelly but the data contained in the block will be read sequentially.

Comment: Yes in most of the cases. But need to remember that InputSplits are there in between Blocks and Tasks. Split boundaries may (most of the cases) or may not map with the Block boundaries. And the task reads the Records inside the Block (Split tells which block to read from). Record boundary may or may not align with the Block boundary. If it is not aligned a Task will continue reading till the end of the Record is reached. This end of the record could be there in another Block. So a Task will end up reading data from 2 blocks.